# Please translate the following shloka from Kaulavali Tantra

Tags: translation-request, tantra, shloka, yantra

I'd like to to know the meaning of the following sloka from "Kaulavali Tantra":

> Yantram mantramayam proktam mantratma devataiva hi
>
> Dehatmanor yatha bhedo yantra-devata yoshtatha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verse is talking about the abheda (non-difference) that exists between yantra, mantra and devata.

There is a very similar verse in the Kularnava Tantra's 6th chapter (86th verse).

> yantram mantramayam proktam devata mantrarupini | 
>  yantre sa
> pujita devi sahasaiva prasidati ||
>
> Yantra is endowed with mantras (or mantric qualities); and devata is
> of the form of mantra; (that's why) O Devi, a deity is readily pleased
> when worshipped in yantra.

The last portion of your verse means that whatever difference there exists between man (mind) and deha (body) the same difference exists between yantra and devata. That is there is no difference at all between a devata and his yantra.

The overall import of the verse is that the mantra of the devata, his yantra and devata himself are one. There is no difference between the three.

**Edit:**
The verse you are looking to find the meaning of (in comments under my answer) is the 88th verse of the same chapter.
Here it is in full along with the meaning:

> Sariram iva jivasya dipasya snehavat priye |
>  Sarveshamapi devanam
> tatha yantram pratishtitam |
>
> O beloved, just as there is body for the jiva, and as there is ghee
> (or oily substance) for the dipa (or lamp),(in a similar manner) all
> deities have their yantras established.

This verse reiterates the fact that there is virtually no difference between the deity and it's yantra. They are inseparable. There is oneness between them.

Hope all your queries are answered now.

Comment: Dear Rickross, Thank you so much for your help (^o^)  Do you know the verse number in Kularnava Tantra such as "yantram mantramayam proktam devata mantrarupini | shariram iva jivasya dipasya snehavat prie sarvesam api devanam tatha yantra...  " ?

Comment: Dear Rickross, me again. I forgot to ask you. Could you translate the portion of Kularnava Tantra which I wrote above question; "sharīram iva jīvasya dīpasya snehavat prie"?  Thank you.

Comment: @Radhikadasi yes I will let you know the verse number. The verse is there in the same chapter.

Comment: You can check the updated answer @Radhikadasi

Comment: Dear Rickross, Thank you so much for your help (^o^) Because of your mercy, I solved my problem. I really appreciate.

Comment: No problem  I am happy to be able to help@Radhikadasi